# golang de-reference a map

Tags: go, garbage-collection, go-map

Here is a sample code that creates a Map of string keys having value of bool.

```
myMap := make(map[string]bool)

myMap["Jan"] = true
myMap["Feb"] = false
myMap["Mar"] = true
```

After doing some operation on this map, I want to delete it. I don't want to use for loop to iterate through each key and delete.

If I do re-initialize myMap again (like following), does it de-references the original and subject to garbage collection?

```
myMap = make(map[string]bool)
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Why do you ask?

Comment: I am very new to go, and was not sure if this is the right way of de-referencing.

Comment: In Go "dereferencing" is the process of dereferencing a pointer to the value it points to, e.g. `*p`. There is no need to do "dereferencing to allow garbage collection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Golang FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap) on garbage collection:

> Each variable in Go exists as long as there are references to it. If
>   the compiler cannot prove that the variable is not referenced after
>   the function returns, then the compiler must allocate the variable on
>   the garbage-collected heap to avoid dangling pointer errors.

In case there are no references used for the current map it will be garbage collected by the language. But for deleting a map There is no process other than looping over it and delete the keys one by one. as

```
myMap := make(map[string]bool)
for k, _ := range myMap{
    delete(myMap, k)
}
```

If you re-initialze the map using `make` it will not going to de-reference the same it will clear the map but will not dereference it. If you check for its len it will become `zero`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    myMap := make(map[string]bool)

    myMap["Jan"] = true
    myMap["Feb"] = false
    myMap["Mar"] = true
    fmt.Println(len(myMap))
    myMap = make(map[string]bool)
    fmt.Println(len(myMap))

}
```

Along with that if you prints the address it points to same address.

```
fmt.Printf("address: %p \n", &myMap)
myMap = make(map[string]bool)
fmt.Printf("address: %p ", &myMap)
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/B7GnYxBKtOf)